# Multiple Time Series Excel Download

Tags: vba, time-series, vlookup, bloomberg

I'm trying to download multiple EoD Time Series in Excel via

```
BDH("APPL US EQUITY","PX_LAST","01.01.2016","10.01.2017","FX="USD")
BDH("IBM US EQUITY","PX_LAST","01.01.2016","10.01.2017","FX="USD")
```

and so on.

To my knowledge there is no function to download multiple Tickers with one call. But is there any whay to align all the tickers to one time series? And display only one date Column?

Basically I want to get the following

```
Date          APPL   IBM
02.01.2016    100    98
03.01.2016    102    99
...
```

Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: do you seriously believe that you have provided enough information for us to give you a meaningful answer?

Comment: what information do you think is missing? I have multiple tickers and try to download the historical time series. Each bdh function returns a date and a price column. Most of the time two ts dont have the same dates (holidays, etc). I just want to align the ts to one date column.

Comment: web page URL. .... the code that you are using. ... explanation where the code fails. ... the results that you are getting. ... the results that you expect to see.

Comment: @jsotola the question is reasonably clear IMO and includes the formula used by the OP that doesn't work as well as the expected output.

Comment: i guess that i should have looked up what the `bloomberg` tag means, sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I generally do is:

- put the tickers in B1, C1, D1 etc.
- in A2:

  ```
  =BDH(B1,"PX_LAST","01.01.2016","10.01.2017","FX=USD,Days=W,Fill=P,Dates=S")
  ```
- in C2:

  ```
  =BDH(C1,"PX_LAST","01.01.2016","10.01.2017","FX=USD,Days=W,Fill=P,Dates=H")
  ```
- then copy that formula to the right

Short explanation:

- `Days=W` means that you want to include all workdays - that helps aligning the time series
- `Fill=P` means that you want to replace missing values with the previous day's price
- `Dates=S/H` indicates whether you want the column with the dates or not

You can find more about the various overrides in C:/blp/API/Office Tools/api_wizard.chm and select BDH.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this link.  It should do what you want, and more.

http://investexcel.net/multiple-stock-quote-downloader-for-excel/

[image]

Comment: The OP is using the Bloomberg API - not sure how this answers his question.